# AppleScript to refresh iTunes track at a filesystem path

Tags: applescript, itunes

I want an Applescript that refreshes a certain song in iTunes from a file. To address the file in iTunes, i have only the path to the file.

I tried it on my own with "refresh" and "file track" but I'm a total newbie on AppleScript so I didn't got anything to work.

Answer (score 1):

I'm an Applescript noob as well, but I figured out on my own!
It's good to know that you can open the iTunes dictionary and browse for things.
Applescript is a strange language, but a lot of it can be guessed from normal English.

Problems with my solution:

- I can't figure out what the location alias is about, so I'm not sure what to enter here.
- For some reason it does work with selection, but not with library playlist.

My code:

```
tell application "iTunes"
 set the_location to location of current track
 repeat with this_track in selection
  if (get location of this_track) is the_location then
   refresh this_track
   log "match"
  end if
 end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: Found these 2 options... Might want to try that :::

tell application "iTunes" to get POSIX path of (get location of current track)

:::

get every file track of playlist "Library"`